# Break text in different lines with \r\n

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On an ASP.NET MVC the model has the following value:

```
TestViewModel model = new TestViewModel {
  Description = "This is a description test\r\nlorem ipsum\r\nline2\r\n\r\n-item1\r\n-item2"
}
```

On the view I simply have the following:

```
<div>@Model.Description</div>
```

The entire text appears in one line ... The \r\n are not making any effect.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the newline characters to HTML's `<br />` element:

```
<div>@Html.Raw(Model.Description.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))</div>
```

Comment: And let me add: wrap your code into @Html.Raw(...). Can you update it so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Oops, forgot that bit. Updated.